# Why does the Observable not create on the right thread?

Tags: android, network-programming, system.reactive, rx-java, rx-android

```
Observable observable = Observable.from(backToArray(downloadWebPage("URL")))
            .map(new Func1<String[], Pair<String[], String[]>>() {
                @Override
                public Pair<String[], String[]> call(String[] of) {
                    return new Pair<>(of,
                            backToArray(downloadWebPage("URL" + of[0])).get(0));
                }
            });

    observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(
            (new Observer<Pair>() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    // Update user interface if needed
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable t) {
                    // Update user interface to handle error
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Pair p) {
                   offices.add(new Office((String[]) p.first, (String[]) p.second));
                }
           }));
```

This runs and i get android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. I would expect it to run a new thread as set by the subscribeOn() method.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the actual network request is happening in `downloadWebPage()`, the error is in the first line of your code:

```
Observable observable = Observable.from(backToArray(downloadWebPage("http://api.ataxcloudapp.com/v1/franchise/listing/?location=" + ZIPCode)))
```

This is equivalent to:

```
String[] response = downloadWebPage("http://api.ataxcloudapp.com/v1/franchise/listing/?location=" + ZIPCode)

Observable observable = Observable.from(backToArray(response))
```

This should make it clear that `downloadWebPage` is executed - on the main thread - before any `Observable` is even created, let alone subscribed to. RxJava cannot change the semantics of Java in this regard.

What you can do however is something like this (not tested, but should be about right):

```
Observable observable = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String[]>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Subscriber<? super String[]> subscriber) {
            final String[] response = downloadWebPage("http://api.ataxcloudapp.com/v1/franchise/listing/?location=" + ZIPCode);
            if (! subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                subscriber.onNext(backToArray(response));
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            }
        }
)
```

Now your network request will happen only *after* the `Observable` is subscribed to, and will be moved to a the thread you specify in `subscribeOn()`.

Comment: You can use `Observable.defer()` to create the Observable at the moment of subscription. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [defer()](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/defer.html) to postpone the calling of `downloadWebPage` to the moment when you subscribe to the observable.

Example:

```
private Object slowBlockingMethod() { ... }

public Observable<Object> newMethod() {
    return Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(slowBlockingMethod()));
}
```

[Source](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/10/08/grokking-rxjava-part-4/)

Answer (score 0):

You should change from

```
**observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())**
```

to

```
**observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())**
```